# Prove\disprove: Let $F : \Bbb{R}^2\to \Bbb{R}$ a function s.t $\nabla F(x,y)=(0,0)$ for all $(x,y)$, so $F$ is constant.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Prove\disprove:

Let $F : \Bbb{R}^2\to \Bbb{R}$ a function s.t $\nabla F(x,y)=(0,0)$ for all $(x,y)$, so $F$ is constant.

Intuitively this seems true, as this means that all partial derivatives are zero, which means the function is constant with respect to $x$ and $y$, but I find my intuition lacking when it comes to functions with more than one variable.

Is this correct? or am I missing something?

Comment: yes, that's the right intuition, and to prove it carefully, you need to use the fact $\Bbb{R}^2$ is connected, and the mean-value theorem/inequality (the mean-value theorem tells you how to translate information about derivatives into information about the original function).

Comment: Note that  if $f$ is differentiable mapping of connected open set $E\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ into $\mathbb{R}^{m}$, and if $f'(x)=0$ for every $x \in E$, then $f$ is constant in $E$.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you should reduce the question to the 1d case, where this statement is definitely true. To do so, use the connectedness of $\mathbb R^2$ and the chain rule: For any two points $v,w\in\mathbb R^2$, define some smooth curve $\gamma:[a,b]\to\mathbb R^2$ connecting the two (a straight line would be best), and consider the function $F\circ\gamma$. This is a function $[a,b]\to\mathbb R$. Show that it is differentiable and that its derivative is $0$. Use that to show that $F(v)=F(w)$.